# Firefox print preview missing in OSX?

Tags: macos, firefox, printing, preview

I am using the current version of Firefox in Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.1. As I am also using Firefox on Windows, I am used to being able to generate a print preview via the File -> Print preview command. On Mac OSX this command is missing. Is there a way to do this on Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click File > Print (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and then click the PDF menu and choose the first option "Open PDF in Preview". That gives you a preview of what the printout will look like. I wasn't able to verify, but it looks like the PDF a temporary file, and will automatically be cleaned up. So it's not cluttering up your system.

Otherwise, this addon might do the trick https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/printprint-preview/

Comment: Open PDF in Preview is a handy feature although it misses the "inspect element" function provided by the Windows version of Firefox. Since the GCLI was also removed in Firefox 62, there is no tool to inspect the print layout of your page :(